# linux find with exec command never ends

Tags: linux, find, infinite-loop

This is the command i am invoking:

```
find / -name zad1.sh -size -50M -mtime -1 -exec grep "do" {} \;
```

Then it echo's two lines which are correct:

```
do
done
```

But then, it continues doing something and never stops. I have to kill the process manually doing Ctrl+C. Can anyone explain to me what happenned here?
P.S. Im new to Unix-like systems.(im working on Cygwin)

Comment: `find` doesn't just look for 1 instance of a file. It starts at the indicated dir (`/`) in your case, and looks until it has traversed all files and dirs from that starting point. It's still looking! ;-) Some `find`s may have an option that quits, but you'll have to consult your `man find` (and hope it is understandable). Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

You have to add **-quit** option; from the manpage:

```
-quit  Exit immediately.  No child processes will be left running,  but
          no  more  paths specified on the command line will be processed.
          For example, find /tmp/foo /tmp/bar -print -quit will print only
          /tmp/foo.   Any  command  lines  which  have  been built up with
          -execdir ... {} + will be invoked before find exits.   The  exit
          status may or may not be zero, depending on whether an error has
          already occurred.
```

Ps. change the "do" with 'do' ; double quotes interpolates the string within and **do** is a keyword for bash.

Comment: Using single quotes is exactly equivalent to double quotes in this case, and neither are necessary.  It's probably better to just leave them out completely.

Comment: It has nothing to do with child processes, As shown in the comment by @shellter, the reason is wrong path specified in the command line.